# Youtube API v3 get the Channel ID of user that uploaded a certain video

Tags: javascript, youtube-api, youtube-data-api, youtube-javascript-api

I want to get the channel ID of a user that uploaded a certain YouTube video on javascript to  after that comparing the channel id to see if it's in an array.

The thing is, I can't find exactly how to get that from javascript. I tried to get:

```
https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/videos?part=snippet&id=[Video ID]&key=[my key]
```

but it gives me JSON parsing error on every video.
Anyone knows how to do it exactly using YouTube API? Doesn't matter if I have to add an exteral script on the html part.

And, as an example of what I want to do, for this video:

```
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=jNQXAC9IVRw
```

it should return `'UC4QobU6STFB0P71PMvOGN5A'`.

Any idea on how to do it?

Comment: _"it gives me JSON parsing error"_. Can you elaborate on this? It works fine for me, I get the JSON containing the channel ID. Perhaps show us the part of the code where you get the JSON and parse it

Comment: Also, I _(or anyone else)_ could give you an example, but for that I would need to know: are you doing this front-end _(in a browser)_ or back-end _(NodeJS)_? Are you using a library to make the request to the Youtube API? If so, which one? (that's why you should post the relevant parts of your code. [Read this](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve))

Comment: @blex If I request, for example,https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/videos?part=snippet&id=jNQXAC9IVRw&key=[MY_KEY] and I parse the JSON result, it gives me the following error: `Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token X in JSON at position 49`. It gives the exact same error on all the videos I tried.

Comment: @blex I'm doing this in front-end, without library (just with pure javascript)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I took the Ajax code from [youmightnotneedjquery.com](http://youmightnotneedjquery.com/#json) and edited it a bit to make a `getJSON` utility function. This worked for me:

```
var API_KEY = 'YOUR_API_KEY'; // Replace this with your own key

getJSON(
  'https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/videos?part=snippet&id=jNQXAC9IVRw&key=' + API_KEY,
  function (err, data) {
    if (err) {
        alert(err);
    } else {
        alert(data.items[0].snippet.channelId);
    }
  }
);

function getJSON(url, callback) {
  var request = new XMLHttpRequest();
  request.open('GET', url, true);

  request.onload = function() {
    if (request.status >= 200 && request.status < 400) {
      // We have the JSON, now we try to parse it
      try {
        var data = JSON.parse(request.responseText);
        // It worked, no error (null)
        return callback(null, data);
      } catch(e) {
        // A parsing arror occurred
        console.error(e);
        return callback('An error occurred while parsing the JSON.');
      }
    }
    // If an error occurred while fetching the data
    callback('An error occurred while fetching the JSON.');
  };

  request.onerror = function() {
    // There was a connection error of some sort
    callback('An error occurred while fetching the JSON.');
  };

  request.send();
}
```